# Must a WebAuthn Client be a web browser?

Tags: webauthn

Must a [WebAuthn Client](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#webauthn-client) be a web browser? Or could it be a command-line interface application?

In particular, I'm interested in a command-line application doing passwordless [authentication](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-usecase-authentication). I understand passwordless requires [a special authenticator](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-3/#first-factor-roaming-authenticator) such as a fingerprint sensor.

> User-verifying platform authenticators and first-factor roaming authenticators enable passwordless multi-factor authentication. In addition to the proof of possession of the credential private key, these authenticators support user verification as a second authentication factor, typically a PIN or biometric recognition. The authenticator can thus act as two kinds of authentication factor, which enables multi-factor authentication while eliminating the need to share a password with the Relying Party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebAuthn is a JS API. Non-browser use is typically via a set of translated APIs and then either integration into the platform's FIDO2 services or direct implementation of CTAP2 (if possible, on the platform).

What specifically are you trying to do? A command line tool does not typically have an origin that is useable with FIDO2/WebAuthn. Many CLI tools pop a default browser for sign in flows, as the experience is much more seamless and provide a richer UI/UX.